# google analytics not tracking custom dimension in context to events

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I need to differentiate the users (Internal and External) who are performing some event action. so I am using the following code to track the user using custom dimension. My end goal is to know who performed the specific event by internal or external user

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Contract Change', 'click', 'Landing Page', 'My Value', {
  'dimension3': 'External'
});

ga('send', 'event', 'Contract Change', 'click', 'Landing Page', 'My Value', {
  'dimension3': 'Internal'
});
```

I have triggered this tracking code from javascript console for the testing purpose however it's not logging any data and I am not able to get the custom dimension value at any of the place.

Comment: The starting point would be to change "my value" - this expects an integer. The idea of the event value is to monetize events that have no intrinsic value. Sending the wrong data type might cause errors.

Answer (score 0):

I would change a couple of things:

- **Integers for event value**: like Eike Pierstorff said, the event value has to be an integer. Technically you could leave the field out as it's optional, but it's best practice to assign values to your goal, so you can quantity the importance of user actions on your website:
  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events#event_fields
- **Set dimensions before events**: what you're doing should work, however it makes the code harder to read (most code formatting will break the `{}` syntax into 2 lines). Also, if you're sending multiple events which should be associated with the dimension, it's just cleaner to have the dimension declaration first, then all your events. Finally, if it's a user-scope dimension (internal vs. external users), it's more logical to declare the dimension before events, otherwise it looks like the dimension is hit-scope:

For instance:

```
ga('set', 'dimension3', 'Internal');  
ga('send', 'event', 'Contract Change', 'click', 'Landing Page', 10);
ga('send', 'event', 'Other event with dimension', 'foo', 'bar', 20);
```